# \insertshorttitle with frame titles and \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

Tags: beamer, notes

The MWE below does not work when `\insertshorttitle` is used as the title of the frame *if* `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}` is active as well. W/o either it works fine. `\inserttitle` does not exhibit this behavior. Why? Is this a bug in beamer?

```
\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\title[This is the rather long short title]{This is the title}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}{\inserttitle}
\begin{frame}{\insertshorttitle}
  Nono :(

  \insertshorttitle within the frame works fine
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The error message I receive is:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\beamer@stend ->\egroup
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why this problem occurs, but as a workaround you could put `\insertshorttitle` into an additional group:

```
\documentclass[
 %notes % This option is obsolete
 ]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\title[This is the rather long short title]{This is the title}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{{\insertshorttitle}}
  Nono :(

  \insertshorttitle within the frame works fine
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```